# MUI and React - inline check if radio button is selected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change the color of a radio button label if that button is checked.

I have value stored in useState() and I'm trying to do an inline check of on a vlue of a radio button if it matches what's in useState().

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState("female");
```

...

```
  <FormControlLabel
     sx={{ color: (this.value === value ? "red" : "blue")}}
     value="bunn"
     control={<Radio />}
     label="Bunn"
  />
```

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal .... I'm trying to check the value of that radio button vs the value stored in useState()

Comment: in your radio value is 'bunn' which is static then you can directly compare with value stored in state if this.value is not working

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal, I tried 'this.value === value' and I'm not seeing the expected result. So how do I do that inline check?

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal ... figured it out based on your 2nd comment - if you want to make it the answer I'll accept it :-) Thanks!

Comment: Remove that condition and check with the value === 'bunn'. Let's see if it works.

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal, that's exactly what I did. Worked like a charm, of course.

Comment: So are you satisfied with the approach I shared or still looking something else?

Comment: Yes, make it your answer, pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.value` doesn't refer to value of radio button here, that's why while comparing state `value` and `this.value` it never matches.
Change `this.value` to exact radio button value (here it's "bunn").

```
<FormControlLabel
  sx={{ color: (value === "bunn" ? "red" : "blue")}}
  value="bunn"
  control={<Radio />}
  label="Bunn"
/>
```